# Loop not exiting if roll_more == 'no'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I tried making a simple dice rolling program, and I can get the dice to 'roll' but I can't stop it, it only keeps if you enter anything. I tried to add it so if you say 'no' or 'n' it will **return** and go to my other functions as usual. I say return because continuing to my other code is important. Thank you.

```
import random
min = 1
def rolling6():
    roll_more = "yes"
    while roll_more == "yes" or roll_more =="y":
        max = 6
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are...")
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        roll = input("Roll the die again? ")

    if roll_more == "no" or roll_more == "n":
        return
    #roll_again = "yes"
    #while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again =="y":
    #   print("Rolling the dices...")
    #   print("The values are...")
    #   print(random.randint(min, 6))
    #   print(random.randint(min, 6))
    #   roll_again = input("Roll the die again? ")

    #if roll_again == "no" or roll_again == "n":
    #   return


x = input("Use six sided die? ") 
while x == "yes" or x =="y":
    rolling6()
```

Comment: the user input is assigned to variable `roll` and you are checking the `roll_more`. Note that the checks can be also be done like `if roll_more.lower() in ['yes', 'y']:` to save space and make sure lowercase is used. A value of `No` would be understood as `yes` by your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to `roll` instead of `roll_more`, so you are always checking against the constant "yes".

Furthermore, your `x` and `roll_more` variables don't hold the values you expect. First, you input "yes" to enter the loop, for `rolling6` to ever be called. Then, you enter the rolling6 loop. When you exit out of that by inputing "no", you exit out to the outer loop, read `x` which still has the value "yes" (since you never overwrote it in any place), which means you don't break out of that loop, and that you enter back into `rolling6` again.

You probably want to change `roll` to `roll_more` and change `while x == "yes" or x =="y":` to `if x == "yes" or x =="y":`.

Also, your `if roll_more == "no" or roll_more == "n": return` is redundant, since there's no code after that statement.